# Launching an Activity with an Intent

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I have the following  in my AndroidManifest:

```
<activity android:name="IntentChild"
          android:label="@string/app_name">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.EDIT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <data android:mimeType="vnd.intent.cursor.item/intent_example"
              android:host="example.intent"
              android:path="intent_example"
              android:scheme="content"
        />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

I launch the activity with

```
Uri uri = new Uri.Builder().scheme("content").authority("example.intent").appendPath("intent_example").build(); 
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_EDIT, uri); 
IntentExample.this.startActivity(intent);
```

But I get:

```
E/AndroidRuntime( 865): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.EDIT dat=content:// 
example.intent/intent_example }
```

What am I doing wrong? Also, does `Uri.Builder.authority()` refer to the same thing as the  `android:host` attribute of the `<data>` tag in my manifest?

Comment: Seems I had to use `intent.setDataAndType(uri, "vnd.intent.cursor.item/intent_example");` and to take out the `android:host` attribute to get the Activity to launch. Not sure why the `host` won't work.

Comment: @A--C Thanks. I'll give that a try. Feel free to post an actual answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prompted by the comment by @A--C, I ended up adding a call to `Intent.setType()` to set the desired MIME type:

```
Uri uri = new Uri.Builder().scheme("content").authority("example.intent").appendPath("intent_example").build(); 
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_EDIT, uri); 
intent.setType("vnd.intent.cursor.item/intent_example");
IntentExample.this.startActivity(intent);
```

For simplicity, I also pruned my `<intent-filter>` to only declare the `android:mimeType`. I guess, but not entirely certain, that this isn't as important as the previous change.

```
<activity android:name="IntentChild"
          android:label="@string/app_name">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.EDIT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <data android:mimeType="vnd.intent.cursor.item/intent_example"/>
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```